# How to inherit step definitions between steps files, Python Selenium Behave

Tags: python, inheritance, pageobjects, python-behave

The below picture is representative of my steps folder.

[image: file org]

Here, when i run my feature file for "childsteps.py", i need it to execute the steps in "parentsteps.py" first then execute the steps in "childsteps.py".

How do i achieve this?, How do i Import those step definitions?

I first thought i should put the step definitions of each file in class and import that class, but I am unable to deduce how I would do this.
Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

In your childsteps.py :

```
from parentsteps import *
```

Then you can call your steps like that

```
credentials()
```

As asked in the comments, to call all the functions of parentsteps.py

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import parentsteps

for f in getmembers(parentsteps, isfunction):
    f[0]()
```

(not tested)

Comment: what would i do if parentsteps.py had 30+ functions.? @Kureteiyu

Comment: Oh you want to call them all?

Comment: yes what if i had like 30 steps, it would be hard to type out all of them. @Kureteiyu

Comment: I edited my message, does my code do what you want?

Comment: I will have to attempt it

Answer (score 0):

Just saw that message. In our case, there would be an "environment.py", where all steps python files are registered under context. So in your child python class, it would be called as if:

```
context.parents.dosomething()
```